# Why is Net::HTTP.get_response throwing an error Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)?

Tags: ruby, capybara, httpurlconnection

I am trying to make a HTTP request using Capybara. When I attempt to execute the code below:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

I get an error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

When I try the URI passed into the method explicitly it works perfectly. URL is an absolute address to the localhost starting with `http://`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The contents of `uri` are probably not what you expect.

Comment: Wait, if this is Capybara, why aren't you using `visit(url)`?

Comment: I need the content of response.